# Music21, window analysis get time?

Tags: python, music21

I tried the WindowAnalysis from music21. However I was wondering how i can convert the index of the window, into the time (in seconds or so) of the song. So for example how could I know at which time the first window is played? e.g. 2.5 seconds into the song

```
s = music21.converter.parse('../data/medley/15046.midi')

p = music21.analysis.discrete.KrumhanslSchmuckler()
wa = music21.analysis.windowed.WindowedAnalysis(s, p)
windo_count=4
a, b = wa.analyze(windo_count)
song = pm.PrettyMIDI('../data/medley/15046.midi')
cello_program = pm.instrument_name_to_program('Cello')
cello = pm.Instrument(program=cello_program)

prev=a[0]
change_loc=[]
#some code that detects change and should append now the time in seconds
for i,beat in enumerate(a[1:]):
    #i is the tuple (key,major/minor/etc,time)
    if beat[0]!=prev[0] and beat[1]!=prev[1]:
        #key changed, at index
        change_loc.append(my_question)
```

Comment: Well, I guess you need to first know the sample rate used Then just apply : `my_question/sampling_rate`

Comment: I checked the doc and there is no information about sampling rate so you can try to find it yourself if you got the length (in time seconds) of your analyzed sample `s`.

Comment: Issue with that approach is that the bpm is not consistent through my dataset. Was kinda hoping there must be sth in music21 or prettymidi or so

Comment: BPM is not related to sample rate. Do you have the entire time length of `s` in seconds ?

Comment: the time would be 450 seconds here, thanks for the help i found a mapping now though, but for curiosity how would i use this to calculate the location of a beat?

Comment: Ok nice. My bet was then to get the inverse of the sampling rate which correspond to one period and one index in your for loop : 450/a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using pretty_midi one can obtain a mapping from beat to time e.g.

```
import pretty_midi as pm
song = pm.PrettyMIDI('data/medley/15046.midi')
print(song.get_beats())
```

EDIT:
More information can be found here: [How to convert bar count to time, in midi? (music)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107146/how-to-convert-bar-count-to-time-in-midi-music)